# how to view which device uses the other person from the imessage conversation?

Tags: macos, message, imessage

I was recently chatting over imessage through the messages app on macbook pro os x yosemite. Somehow the person I was chatting with knew exactly on which device I was chatting from. How can I see this? I have tried to view the message source, but could not find anything that would get me to this info.

Answer (score 0):

The Messages app probably spews debug info to the console.  Try running the Console app (in Applications/Utilities) and see what it shows.  Failing that, there's also a Connection doctor window that might have some info.  Those are just guesses, though; I'd have to chat with somebody to say for sure.  :-)